# PHPUnit - Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'buildViolation' when invoked 1 time(s)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am new to Symfony 4 and I have been testing Validation.

I have this error.

*Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'buildViolation' when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.*

What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

This is the content of my Validator

```
namespace CoreBundle\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use UserBundle\Service\FilterNameService;

class FilterNameValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private FilterNameService $filterNameService;

    public function __construct(FilterNameService $filterNameService)
    {
        $this->filterNameService = $filterNameService;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed      $value      The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($this->filterNameService->haveForbiddenWord($value)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the content of my Validator Test

```
namespace Tests\CoreBundle\Validator;

use CoreBundle\Validator\FilterName;
use CoreBundle\Validator\FilterNameValidator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Violation\ConstraintViolationBuilderInterface;
use UserBundle\Service\FilterNameService;

class FilterNameValidatorTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public FilterNameService $filterNameService;
    public FilterNameValidator $filterNameValidator;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
        $this->filterNameService = $this->getMockBuilder(FilterNameService::class)
             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
             ->getMock();
    }


    public function testCatchBadNames()
    {
        $validator = new FilterNameValidator($this->filterNameService);

        $violation = $this->getMockBuilder(ConstraintViolationBuilderInterface::class)->getMock();
        $violation->expects($this->any())->method('setParameter')->willReturn($violation);
        $context = $this->getMockBuilder(ExecutionContextInterface::class)->getMock();

        $context
                ->expects($this->once())
                ->method('buildViolation');

        $validator->initialize($context);

        return $validator;

    }
}
```

Comment: And where does your validator run __validate()__ method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `validate` method inside the `testCatchBadNames` method.